# How to remove item from bounded List of Views injected by ButterKnife?

Tags: android, butterknife

I have a List of Views that injected via ButterKnife

```
@BindViews({
        R.id.legend_txt_SB, R.id.legend_txt_MB, R.id.legend_txt_B_LOW,
        R.id.legend_txt_B_HIGH, R.id.legend_txt_Normal, R.id.legend_txt_A_LOW,
        R.id.legend_txt_A_HIGH, R.id.legend_txt_MA, R.id.legend_txt_SA
})
List<TextView> labels;
```

And in some case I need to remove 4 and 5 item from this list. I tried next :

```
    if (<expression>) {
        labels.get(4).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        labels.get(5).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        labels.remove(4);
        labels.remove(5);
    }
```

and got error :

```
  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException 
  at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:638)
```

Note. I don't want to **disable** views. I want to **remove** them.

Comment: why you want to remove if i may ask?

Comment: @ColdFire I use Binding in class, that playing a role like a one-shot object. 
This 9 Views displaying as table 3x3. And In some case I need fill all of them, except 4,5 item. Otherwise 4,5 should be dismissed. Really don't like jumping around code with Strategy pattern :(

Comment: The docs for either `AbstractList.remove` and `List.remove` read: "Removes the element at the specified position in this list **(optional operation)**." So you can not rely on that operation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to remove the view from the screen, not the list.
To do that, you can either hide it using `setVisibility` or

```
((ViewGroup) labels.get(4).getParent()).removeView(labels.get(4));
```

The list contains only pointers to the actual view. I think that you get the exception because "remove" is not implemented in the list ButterKnife returned.

- If I where you, I wouldn't use ButterKnife for these particular views, or create a separate field for them in my activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think, `ButterKnife` annotation does not allow different type than `List`. Probably, you can try doing:

```
@BindViews({
        R.id.legend_txt_SB, R.id.legend_txt_MB, R.id.legend_txt_B_LOW,
        R.id.legend_txt_B_HIGH, R.id.legend_txt_Normal, R.id.legend_txt_A_LOW,
        R.id.legend_txt_A_HIGH, R.id.legend_txt_MA, R.id.legend_txt_SA
})
ArrayList<TextView> labels;
```

`UnsupportedOperationException` due to `AbstractList` does not support removing elements, if the `List` implementation does not have interator that can do removal. Also you can try removing the elements with casting to implementation first:

```
((ArrayList)labels).remove(4);
((ArrayList)labels).remove(5);
```